# Sort filename like abc 1.1, abc 1.1.1, abc 1.0 in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I have used natsort(), but it didn't work as I want to have.

It display sorted array like this:

1) abc 1.0

2) abc 1.1.1

3) abc 1.1

But I want:

1) abc 1.0

2) abc 1.1

3) abc 1.1.1

So, please tell what is the possible solution of this in php

Comment: Where is placed `def 1.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$array = array('abc 1.0','abc 1.1.1','abc 1.1','xyz 1.1','def 2.0');
function fct($a, $b) {
    list($al, $an) = explode(' ', $a);
    list($bl, $bn) = explode(' ', $b);
    if ( $al == $bl ) return version_compare($an, $bn);
    return strcmp($al, $bl);
}
usort($array, 'fct');
print_r($array);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc 1.0
    [1] => abc 1.1
    [2] => abc 1.1.1
    [3] => def 2.0
    [4] => xyz 1.1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function csort($a, $b) {
    $a = preg_split("/\s+/", $a);
    $b = preg_split("/\s+/", $b);
    return version_compare($a[1], $b[1]);
}

$r = array('abc 1.1', 'abc 1.0', 'abc 1.1.1');
usort($r, "csort");
```

or simply

```
usort($r, "version_compare");
```

as proposed by @onetrickpony.

Comment: `usort($r, "version_compare");` should work just fine, no need for anything else

Comment: @onetrickpony tnx for comment

Answer (score 0):

Define your own compare function and use [usort](http://php.net/usort)

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $a);
    $b = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $b);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
$arr = array('abc 1.1', 'abc 1.0', 'abc 1.1.1');

usort($arr, "cmp");
print_r($arr);
?>
```

you can think about better compare algorithm if needed

Comment: A better compare algorithm might entail splitting the filename and version, and then using [version_compare()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)